# Dataloader Across Org's = How to match Contacts to their Accounts?

Tags: data-loader, salesforce-id, excel, merge

If I move an **Account** from *Production to Sandbox*, then when it's time to move the **Contacts** from *Production to Sandbox*, then in Excel, in the Contact CSV, I just update the AccountID Cell with the *new* Account number that the Sandbox gave that account. That way, the Contact finds it's owner.

How do I do this for 100,000 accounts? I can't individually assign them all their new AccountID.

I'm just trying to find the path of least resistance and the best practice here.

Thanks

Comment: For this reason you have to create an external id field and load your data. This way you don't have to get the id of the record always, you can keep this external id value consistent across orgs.

Comment: In most cases it would be preferable to (automatically) create those accounts and contacts in your  sandbox with fake data. However, that does depend on your use case

Comment: So you're saying create an ExternalID on Account, Opportunity, Contacts, Pricebooks, etc.? How would they update, do i have to save them all or does it automatically apply upon field creation? And is the ExternalID on account, going to be the exact same on that Accounts Opportunities, Contacts, Pricebooks, etc.?

Comment: N.B. pricebooks will automatically copy when the sandbox is created/refreshed. You could also consider partial copy sandboxes

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from another source:

On the Account extract relabel the ID field to something else (ex. Prod_Id) then your success file from the import will contain the Prod_Id field.  You can use that to do a vlookup on your Contact extract.